# How do I match the pattern in android

Tags: android, design-patterns, matching

I am currently working on an android project. I would like to know if a string  contains the '\r' or '\n' as the last character. How to do the pattern match?

Comment: Use Regex to do that

Comment: could you be more specific? I am pretty new to Android development. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you just want to find out if the last characters are `\r or \n` or you also want to find it out inbetween string?

Comment: just the last character. Thanks

Comment: I will try it tomorrow to see which one is really working. Too late now. Thanks. I will give the final acceptance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
String string = "stackoverflow";
lastchar = string.substring(string.length() - 1);
```

It will give you the result "w".

Comment: This doesn't provide you with the answer, isn't it?

Comment: I tried this solution a moment ago. And it is working. I will accept this one. I think the rest answers here should also work but this solution seems to be the most simplest one. Thanks all for your ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String  patterntomatch ="^[_A-Za-z0-9-]*(\r\n)$";
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(patterntomatch);
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(matchfromedittext);

    boolean matcher.matches();
```

Comment: what happen...doesn't it satified the answer u want?

Answer (score 0):

```
String last = your_string.substring(Math.max(your_string.length() - 2, 0));
//It will give you the last 2 characters of the string. If the string is null 
//or has less than 2 characters, then it gives you the original string.

if(last.equals("\r") || last.equals("\n")){
    //String's last two characters are either \n or \r. Now do something.
}
```